# I need to capitalize everything after a the colon in an entered program

Tags: java

Hello so I am a first year computer science student that needs some help. I am assigned to make a program that I can enter a string into and then based on what I enter it changes. So if I enter something with a colon, the output is everything after the colon capitalized and if there is no colon then everything is capitalized. So far I know I need to use an if function as well as index of but I am not quite sure how. Below I will put what I currently have. The int = indexOf is not working for some reason if anyone can give me any advice I will greatly appreciate it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringFunctions
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

       String text;
       System.out.print ( "Input> " ) ;
       String input = user_input.next();

       final int a = indexOf( " : " );

       if ( a = 1)
       System.out.println ( "yay" );

       System.out.println( "output> " + input.trim().toUpperCase() );//; initialise instance variables

    }
```

Comment: **JAVASCRIPT != JAVA**

Comment: You should change your `if(a=1)` to `if(a==1)` . `=` is assignment and `==` is comparision

Comment: But I still get an error with the index of :

Comment: indexOf() is a method of the clas String. You must call it on a String object: input.indexOf(':'). Also, `" : "` is not a colon. It's a space followed by a colon followed by a space.

Comment: I'm sorry this is probably silly, but how do I make it a String object? I mistyped I have indexOf( " : ");

Answer (score 0):

You're using indexOf wrong. The correct syntax to find the index of the first occurrence of `:` in the string stored in variable `text` is `text.indexOf(":");`

Comment: when I change it to that I get the error that variable text might not have been initialized.

Comment: The compiler is correct. You haven't initialized the variable `text`, you've just instantiated it.

`String text;` is instantiation, it just means "there's a variable called `text` and it has type `String`, but it doesn't put anything into that variable. 

`text = [some code here]` is what will set the value of the variable `text` to whatever the code produces. That's initialization.

Comment: I'm sorry I am really not understanding what you are saying. We aren't very far in my CS class, what would you recommend I do to fix the issue I am having?

Comment: In contrast to the variable `text`, which is only instantiated by your code, the variable `input` is both instantiated and initialized (it's set to the value of `user_input.next()`)

Comment: Alright that makes sense but I am just confused on what I have to do in order to fix this program and make it work. I know this is beginner stuff but I don't quite understand how it works

Comment: @MatthewBush it's not instantiation. It's a declaration. A variable is declared, and initialized. A class can be instantiated. That happens when you create an instance of the class, i.e. when you call its constructor.

Comment: It's fine that it's beginner stuff; everyone has to start somewhere. I'm not going to write your program for you, though. The point is to help you understand it, not just blindly follow what someone said on the internet. Can you edit your question to fix some of the problems that have been pointed out, and ask a specific question?

Comment: @JBNizet d'oh! You're totally right. Editing... Except apparently I can't edit my own comment now? Not sure why not.